# What is the output of this simple java code 6 and not 4?

Tags: java

What is the output of this simple java code 6 and not 4? Also since int x = 10 and int y = 15, how come they are able to declare int x and int y again to be 5 and x-2? I thought you can only declare the value of an int once? thanks, sorry I'm new to java.

here's the code:

```
public class shortq
{
     public static void main (String args[])
     {
         int x = 10 , y =15;
         x = 5;
         y = x-2;
         System.out.println(x+1);
     }
}
```

Comment: because `5 + 1 = 6`? After `x=5` `x` does not get changed again.

Comment: `I thought you can only declare the value of an int once` why did you think that?

Comment: You do not declare the value of an int - you declare variables of some types (i.e. you declare a variable x of type int) and you assign values to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also since int x = 10 and int y = 15, how come they are able to
>   declare int x and int y again to be 5 and x-2? I thought you can only
>   declare the value of an int once? thanks, sorry I'm new to java.

```
x = 5;
 y = x-2;
```

with above you are not declaring the variable but doing assignment. So in your post there is only one time declaration i.e  `int x = 10 , y =15;`

> How is the output of this simple java code 6 and not 4?

as x is 5 and then you are adding 1 to it while printing

```
 x = 5;
 System.out.println(x+1);
```